# Master tasks on Core Nodes using AWS EMR Hadoop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr, mrjob

Using EMR 6.X series, how does one ensure that master tasks run on Core nodes? Reading [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html) it looks like all it takes are two parameters:

```
    yarn.node-labels.enabled: true
    yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression: 'CORE'
```

However in my tests this doesn't work. Specifically, I am using [mrjob](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and here is my setup:

**test.py**

```
import time

from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
from mrjob.protocol import RawValueProtocol, JSONProtocol

class Test(MRJob):
    INPUT_PROTOCOL = RawValueProtocol
    INTERNAL_PROTOCOL = JSONProtocol

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper,
                reducer=self.reducer)
        ]

    def mapper(self, _, fname):
        # sleep so things stay "running" until we are ready to stop it
        time.sleep(1000000000)

    def reducer(self, key, datas):
        time.sleep(10000000)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.run()
```

**mrjob.conf**

```
runners:
  emr:
    region: us-east-1
    subnet: subnet-...
    ec2_key_pair: ...
    ec2_key_pair_file: ...
    ssh_tunnel: false
    check_cluster_every: 30
    cleanup: NONE
    cleanup_on_failure: NONE
    read_logs: false
    add_steps_in_batch: true
    cat_output: false
    image_version: 6.3.0

    instance_fleets:
    - InstanceFleetType: MASTER
      InstanceTypeConfigs:
      - InstanceType: m6g.xlarge
      TargetOnDemandCapacity: 1
    - InstanceFleetType: CORE
      TargetOnDemandCapacity: 1
      InstanceTypeConfigs:
      - InstanceType: m6g.xlarge
        BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice: 100
        WeightedCapacity: 1
    - InstanceFleetType: TASK
      TargetOnDemandCapacity: 0
      TargetSpotCapacity: 1
      InstanceTypeConfigs:
      - InstanceType: m6g.xlarge
        BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice: 100
        WeightedCapacity: 1

    bootstrap:
    - sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
    - curl -L https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh
    - bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /home/hadoop/miniconda
    - rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
    - /home/hadoop/miniconda/bin/conda update conda -y
    - /home/hadoop/miniconda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge -y -q pip
    - /home/hadoop/miniconda/bin/pip install mrjob
    bootstrap_python: false
    bootstrap_mrjob: false
    python_bin: /home/hadoop/miniconda/bin/python -W ignore
    emr_configurations:
      - Classification: hdfs-site
        Properties:
          dfs.replication: 1
      - Classification: mapred-site
        Properties:
          mapreduce.map.memory.mb: 1000
          mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb: 1000
          mapreduce.job.reduces: 5
          mapreduce.job.maps: 5
      - Classification: yarn-site
        Properties:
          yarn.node-labels.enabled: true
          yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression: 'CORE'
```

**test.txt**

```
1
2
3
```

and a command:

```
python test.py -r emr --conf-path mrjob.conf test.txt
```

I get this error:

```
Streaming Command Failed!
Command exiting with ret '5'
```

If I comment out the last four lines of **mrjob.conf** everything works. Any ideas what's going on? I would really like to constrain master tasks to core nodes.